how to add Admob in our react native expo app which expo version is 50 and 51
my package.json is
{
  "name": "admob",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^50.0.18",
    "expo-ads-admob": "^13.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3"
  },
}

i tried the plugins
1, "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.6.0",
2. "expo-ads-admob": "^13.0.0",
not working
how to fix this issue and use in expo 50 or 51

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have to install the version 13.3.0
be sure you install the last version of expo SDK
npm install expo@latest

them
npx expo install --fix

finally
npm install react-native-google-mobile-ads@13.3.0

